# comparing two observable values in knockout data-bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

In my knockout applicatioon i'm trying to compare two observable value and assign class accordingly.

But the evaluation of observable doesnt change event though the value have changes in the observable

Below is the code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
      <span data-bind="text:CurrentPlan().Id "></span>
      <span data-bind="text:CurrentElem().PointPlanId "></span>
      <span data-bind="text:CurrentPlan.Id == CurrentElem.PointPlanId"></span>
      <button class="btn btn-blue btn-alt" type="button" data-bind="click:AssignPlan,
         css: {'disabled':CurrentPlan.Id == CurrentElem.PointPlanId}"> Assign </button>
</div>
```

I can see the value changing in the span added but the expression value doesn't change.

Both currentPlan and currentElem are observables.

Please guide

Thanks

Shruti nair

Comment: You forgot the `()` you need to get the observable value. Try `CurrentPlan().Id == CurrentElem().PointPlanId`

Comment: not working its evaluates to false even when the values are same.

Comment: Please [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If `CurrentPlan` and `CurrentElem` are observables then you need to use brackets () to get the values

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
      <span data-bind="text:CurrentPlan().Id "></span>
      <span data-bind="text:CurrentElem().PointPlanId "></span>
      <span data-bind="text:(CurrentPlan().Id == CurrentElem().PointPlanId)"></span>
      <button class="btn btn-blue btn-alt" type="button" data-bind="click:AssignPlan,
         css: {'disabled':(CurrentPlan().Id == CurrentElem().PointPlanId)}"> Assign </button>
</div>
```

Comment: suppose both CurrentElem and CurrentPlan vaue is 45 still the expression CurrentPlan().Id==CurrentElem().PointPlanId evaluates to false and doesnt change even after the value is updated

Comment: Do you mind showing your JS code as well? Particularly the way the values are getting updated

Answer (score 0):

> I can see the value changing in the span added

In that case I'm assuming `Id` and `PointPlanId` are observables.

So, you should change your code to:

```
css: {'disabled':CurrentPlan().Id() == CurrentElem().PointPlanId()}"
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  const self = this;

  self.CurrentPlan = ko.observable({
    Id: ko.observable(10)
  });
  
  self.CurrentElem = ko.observable({
    PointPlanId: ko.observable(20)
  });

  self.AssignPlan = () => {}
  
  // make the value equal after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(() => self.CurrentPlan().Id(20), 3000);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
  <span data-bind="text:CurrentPlan().Id"></span>
  <span data-bind="text:CurrentElem().PointPlanId"></span>
  <span data-bind="text:CurrentPlan().Id() === CurrentElem().PointPlanId()"></span>
  <button class="btn btn-blue btn-alt" type="button" data-bind="click:AssignPlan,
         css: {'disabled':CurrentPlan().Id() === CurrentElem().PointPlanId()}">Assign</button>
</div>
```

You don't have to use `CurrentPlan().Id()` in the first `text` binding because knockout automatically handles both observables and regular properties using `ko.utils.unwrapObservable`. When you have an expression of some sort involving values of the observables, you need to use `()` to get the observable's value.